# Using MacOS as Internet Gateway

Tags: networking, router, mac, desktop-computer

Currently this is my setup

```
Internet <-- router <--  Mac Pro (Wifi). shared over Ethernet <-- PC (Ethernet)
```

The default network sharing from Mac is very limited. I am able to share my Mac Wifi over ethernet and connect to internet. However this bypasses all VPN routing/VPN setup in Mac and I believe MacOS treats Network sharing as an independent connection.

Apart from typical en0 to en4, have additional network interfaces in ifconfig

```
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 82:cb:7c:65:a0:01
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 9 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 10 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en3 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 11 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en4 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 12 priority 0 path cost 0
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::de2e:1a51:57e:a90a%utun1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xf
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun2: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::1e70:3ce6:794:e31%utun2 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x10
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1400
utun3: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1300
    inet 10.64.0.1 --> 10.64.0.1 netmask 0xffff0000
    inet6 fe80::aede:48ff:fe00:1122%utun3 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x12
    inet6 fc00::6440:1 prefixlen 64
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
en7: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=6467<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether 34:29:8f:70:d9:30
    inet6 fe80::10a0:370:490a:41bb%en7 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x13
    inet 192.168.3.1 netmask 0xffffffff broadcast 192.168.3.1
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
    status: active
bridge100: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 5e:52:30:b9:c1:64
    inet 192.168.2.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
    inet6 fe80::1460:d7c1:2487:e0d4%bridge100 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x14
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: en7 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 19 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

If I connect PC over ethernet, two network interfaces are getting added `en7 (USB Ethernet), bridge100 (internet sharing over USB Ethernet)

How to setup Mac as Internet Gateway or a way where I can route all my requests from PC as if they are originated from Mac (routing through VPN).

PC is running on Linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your VPN is configured, you only need to select your VPN network as the network to share under **Share your connection from**:

[image]

Image and more details [here](https://machow2.com/share-vpn-mac/). This is only allowed by certain VPN protocols like L2TP/PPTP.

---

Another relatively simple option you can try is manually [Bridging](https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/mac-help/mh43557/mac) your ethernet and vpn interfaces. The the internet sharing tool behaves in a similar way, but may not be allowed for your VPN provider/type.

This also **excludes** the Mac from connecting to the bridged networks, because all traffic from the vpn interface goes directly to your ethernet port and out

1. System Preferences > Network > Actions > Manage Virtual Interfaces > Add > New Bridge
2. include your VPN and your Ethernet interfaces
3. Create > Done

This can get pretty weird though when your vpn is disconnected or not running. It may need to be removed before your Mac can connect back to everything normally.

---

Other options really depend on what kind of vpn you have going, whether it will allow multiple clients to be connected, and how complex you want to get. These are all bad recommendations if you're not sure what you're doing:

- You could manually edit your routing table entries to send traffic from your linux machine out your vpn and vice-versa. You'll want to at least be familiar with routing concepts, because adding a bad route *can* totally isolate you from the internet.
- If your vpn requires clients to be on the same IP subnet, you can set up some janky ip addressing or even configure NAT for your ethernet client, in addition to setting up routes.
- If you only need a specific service to go through the vpn from your linux machine (like SSH), then you could configure port-forwarding for it.